# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. "The pipe has been ended."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express, localdb

I'm currently getting the following exception when running some unit tests on our build server connecting an SQL server express instance of SQL localdb.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The pipe has been ended.
```

This error has been popping up lately for various reasons such as reading or inserting test data for the unit tests.

Our development machines and the build server use the default instance of SQL local db (MSSQLLOCALDB) and we've only ever seen this issue appear on the build server. Could this be because the build server is running several sets of unit tests in parallel on the same server and the pipe is being ended for us? Each set of unit tests use their own database so they shouldn't be conflicting with each other.

Looking at similar questions on Stack Overflow and Google I have attempted to resolve the issue by enabling the "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP" protocols for SQLEXPRESS but have had no luck in attempting to resolve the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated and I can provide any extra information if required.

Thanks

Comment: Could we see the code around the area that this exception is thrown?
I'm guessing from the exception that you are writing in C#.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts yeah we're using C# and a mix of Dapper and Dapper Extensions for our ORM. It's a minimal approach for Dapper and we're just calling the standard Dapper Extensions insert method as seen here (https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions#simple-insert-operation).

Our method implementations have not seen this error so far it's just the unit tests that are throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the nuget package we were using for creating our local databases was closing the pipe for the default instance earlier than expected. We fixed this by create a new localdb instance for each set of tests and removing the instance once the tests had been run.

Comment: Could you add some more detail? Experiencing the same issue with running our unit tests with new localdb database per test.